# Is there any way to find url in oracle database 11g?

Tags: url, oracle11g, schema

Is there any way to find url in oracle database 11g ?

Suppose I'm having four different schemas, in all schemas I want to find all the url associated with these schemas, could anyone please tell me the script how can I find that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "url associated with these schemas"? Can you give an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: @pmdba, below is the example.

create or replace package body p_pkg AS

procedure p_url( a in varchar2,
                 b out varchar2)

IS

begin

select (UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('http://stackoverflow.com='||a ))
into b
from dual;
b:= 'TRUE';

END p_url;
end p_pkg;

Comment: Schemas don't have URLs. Are you working with REST-enabled tables or stored procedures?

Comment: under schema any stored procedure like packages/procedure/function.

Are you working with REST-enabled tables or stored procedures?  stored procedures

Comment: If you have Oracle REST configured, then individual objects might have URLs if they are specifically REST-enabled. Otherwise - in general and certainly by default - there is no such thing as a URL for a schema. The example you gave is of a stored procedure accessing some other web site, not an Oracle database.